# Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} in string eq at ./folder1/friends-mysql.cgi line 16

Tags: mysql, perl

I am creating a website which will take user info and store in mysql database. When I run the script through terminal I get the following error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $ENV{"REQUEST_METHOD"} in string eq at ./folder1/friends-mysql.cgi line 16.
```

I am not sure about why I am getting this error. Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;

#Declare Variables with MYSQL Connection Data
$db="my database";
$user="my username";
$passwd="password";
$host="host";
$connectionInfo="";

#Print HTTP header
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

#Check if Method is GET
if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "GET") { -->This is line 16
        &displayform();
        exit;
}
else {             #If Method not GET process form and insert into DB
        &parseform();
        &insertfriend();
        exit;
}

#Standard form parsing using POST method
sub parseform {  
        read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
        @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
        foreach $pair(@pairs) {
                ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
                $value =~ tr/+/ /;
                $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
                $FORM{$name} = $value; 
        }
}
```

Comment: `$ENV{REQUEST_METHOD}` would refer to an enviroment variable called "REQUEST_METHOD". Before running the script have you created and exported an enviroment variable? `export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"`

Comment: @chris-doyle  that's probably the answer so ... you know what to do :-)

Comment: @ChrisDoyle do I have to put `export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"` because I put this in my script, but I am still not getting the result. When I execute the script from a browser I get the entire script as it is.

Comment: Are you running it via a server  or trying or via file? If via. Server and your are getting the contents of the script as opposed to the output it means the server isn't configured to run scripts in that directory and probably needs some config.

Comment: @Doon Yes I forgot to put the file in cgi bin directory. I have moved it there, but the problem is still there. Now I see a blank page. When I check the error_log I see the following: `[Sun Oct 02 19:30:59 2016] [error] [client 173.206.226.134] Use of uninitialized value in read at /home/user1/httpd/new-cgi/friends-mysql.cgi line 18.
[Sun Oct 02 19:32:17 2016] [error] [client 173.206.226.134] Name "main::FORM" used only once: possible typo at /home/user1/httpd/new-cgi/friends-mysql.cgi line`

Comment: I am confused why I am getting the above mentioned error. I created a simple form and it worked perfectly. Could it be because I am not using a seperate file for HTML, so when I try to access the script from browser the server thinks of it as a CGI file and wants to print the contents of script?

Comment: The first error is because `$ENV{CONTENT_LENGTH}` is undefined, and the second is because you haven't declared the hash `%FORM` before accessing `$FORM{$name}`. If you want to use CGI then it would be better to use a module such as [`CGI::Minimal`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Minimal) rather than writing all your own code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

When your program is running as web application, it is the CGI protocol that sets multiple environment variables, including `REQUEST_METHOD`

If you want to test your program from the command line then you must set the requisite variables manually before running the program

Something like this

```
$ export REQUEST_METHOD="GET"
$ ./folder1/friends-mysql.cgi
```

Note that it is also *essential* to add `use strict` to the top of every Perl program you write, and `use warnings 'all'` is preferable to `-w` on the shebang line